# Upload database records to AWS using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aws, sybase-sql-anywhere

We have an AWS account that will be installing some software that ultimately needs a subset of our customers' data.  Our customer databases are either MS SQL Server or Sybase Anywhere.  Is there a way we can run TSQL SELECTs from our customer databases into databases on AWS?  If so, would this be resident on AWS pulling from the customer databases?  Or resident on our customer servers pushing to AWS?  If we were pulling, we would need our customers to provide us access to their IP addresses; is that insecure?

Comment: In AWS do you have RDSs or EC2 instances with DBs ?

Comment: I think we might have an EC2, but perhaps we could also purchase RDS.  We need to automate this and use the simplest tool for the job, and possibly the cheapest.

Comment: perhaps you can share what exactly the software need, so without assuming things , I would describe approaches I use at my current work. 

I normally use powershell to extract the data from dbs, I use SMO [link] http://sqlmag.com/powershell/using-sql-server-management-objects-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you can share what exactly the software need, so without assuming things , I would describe approaches I use at my current work.

I normally use powershell to extract the data from dbs, I use SMO [link] http://sqlmag.com/powershell/using-sql-server-management-objects-powershell

and then you can upload the output to an s3 bucket using write-s3object powershell command , this can be done from any customer environment which has access to internet, and with using the awspowershell module which you can download [link] https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/ and from a central EC2 in your aws you can read this data from s3-bucket , you can use read-s3object to get the data from the s3 bucket

Comment: When I have more information, I can share more.  This answer sounds reasonable at the present time (I know little of the AWS environment right now).